# Futures Options: Options Expiration vs. Underlying Delivery

Tags: options, futures, margin

Does the expiration of a futures option always determine the delivery date of the underlying, in particular does the option always expire into the earliest-delivering futures contract?

For example, /OGH22 (H = March) expires 23 Feb into /GCH22, even though /GCG22 (G = February) settles on 24 Feb.  It seems that /OG always settles a day before the /GC contracts, but they actually settle into the "2nd-earliest contract".

Maybe I should be looking at the month code to tell me what it expires into.  However, /OG4G22 expires on 25 Feb, so there's no way it could settle into /GCG22.

In summary: given the symbol for a futures option, how can I determine the delivery date of the underlying?

Comment: Can you clarify (and add links) as to what options and futures you're looking at it? When I look for those tickers (OGH22 and GCH22) I get unrelated chains.

Comment: [/GC](https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/metals/precious/gold.calendar.options.html#optionProductId=7488) are the futures contracts on gold. [/OG](https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/metals/precious/gold.calendar.options.html#optionProductId=192) are the monthly futures options on /GC. [/OG4](https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/metals/precious/gold.calendar.options.html#optionProductId=7488) are the Week 4 futures options on /GC. Please click links to be taken to the relevant CME calendars.

Comment: The answer to all such questions is the exchange, as they define the contract. You should be able to find the specifics in the contract terms / specification. Note that different exchanges operate differently, so always make sure to check with the one that operates that specific contract.